# How to refresh the one but last ContentPage on the Navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Typically, one pops the current page using this from the NavigationStack:

```
   Navigation.PopAsync( true );
```

**How to I use `Navigation` to redraw the page just before the current page?**

Background: The current page changed something that need to get re-presented in the one but last page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I'm assuming that the data model that you are using is not observable/bindable and thus the page is not "auto-updated"...*

You could use `MessagingCenter` to publish a "Refresh Event" to avoid coupling the two `Page`s with events...

In your MainPage:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "RefreshMainPage", (sender) => {
    // Call your main page refresh method
});
```

In your Second Page:

```
   MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "RefreshMainPage");
   Navigation.PopAsync( true );
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/

Comment: Working... Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

As @SushiHangover mentioned, `MessagingCenter` is a good option.

Another way would be to subscribe to Page2's `OnDisappearing()` event from page1 and do something to the Page1 UI/data like so:

Edit: The old way I answered this question (see changelog) does work but I have since modified how I do it, after seeing others' examples, to prevent memory leaks. It is better to unsubscribe from the `Disappearing` event after it has been used. If you plan to use it again then you can just resubscribe to it before running `PushAsync()` again on your `Page2` instance:

```
private async void OnGoToPage2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    Page2 page2 = new Page2();

    page2.Disappearing += OnPage2Disappearing;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(page2);
}

private async void OnPage2Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {
    await _viewModel.RefreshPage1Data(); //Or how ever you need to refresh the data
    ((Page2)sender).Disappearing -= OnPage2Disappearing; //Unsubscribe from the event to allow the GC to collect the page and prevent memory leaks
}
```

Comment: Totally worked for me.  I had to do it a little differently.

Comment: @MichaelD.Kirkpatrick Glad it helped. Having answered this a little while ago, I just made an edit that should be much better with managing memory. I would suggest taking another look when you can.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I had to do to get hvaughan3's solution to work for me:

```
private async void OnGoToPage2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    Page2 page2 = new Page2();

    page2.Disappearing += Page2_Disappearing;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(page2);
}

private void Page2_Disappearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Refresh(); // what your refresh or init function is.
}
```

When I saw that solution I liked that as the option for me since I'm real heavy into using events to solve most of my problems.  Thanks hvaughan3!