# How to pass data to the previous page using PopAsync?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Consider the following scenario:

1. User is on some Page 1
2. He clicks button that moves him to Page 2 (calling `await Navigation.PushAsync(new SomePage());` )
3. After finishing certain action, he clicks "OK" button
4. After clicking "OK", app calls PopAsync to move to Page 1 and sends there some data (result of activity on Page 2).

How can I receive data from Page 2 in Page 1?

Comment: Are you using ViewModels?

Comment: In which way? For what?

Comment: If you are using ViewModels associated with Pages its easy to share data between pages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way (IMO) would be to handle the pop from the originating page by raising an event. Something like this:

```
public class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public event EventHandler LoginSucceeded;

    public event EventHandler LoginFailed;

    private void OnLoginSucceeded()
    {
        if (LoginSucceeded != null)
        {
            LoginSucceeded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void OnLoginFailed()
    {
        if (LoginFailed != null)
        {
            LoginFailed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

and from app.cs

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage.LoginSucceeded += HandleLoginSucceeded;
        MainPage = loginPage;
    }

    private void HandleLoginSucceeded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

You can read more about it over [here](http://blog.adamkemp.com/2015/03/decoupling-views.html) -- Really good article

Another option is to use **MessagingCenter**

Comment: Looks interesing. Is it possible to do it if I'm not in class that extends from "Application"? I mean: my Page 1 (from where I want to launch Page 2) is ContentPage where there isn't anything like MainPage variable.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 7):

You could use either my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465850/how-to-refresh-the-one-but-last-contentpage-on-the-navigation/37468293#37468293) or SushiHangover's answer on the same page.

My answer will work in a `ContentPage` and SushiHangover's will work anywhere.

My answer involves subscribing to `ContentPage.OnDisappearing` from Page 1 before doing your `PushAsync()`.

If the data being changed is saved to a DB in Page 2, you can just use Page 1's `OnAppearing()` event to always pull fresh from the DB, which would pull in the new data that was changed on Page 2. `OnAppearing()` would get executed after Page 2 is popped and the user is returning to Page 1.