# How to understand which page was previously opened

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In the `OnAppearing()` method it is possible to understand if the user was previously returning from a particula page?
I would like to understand when the user returns to `MainPage` if they have previously been in the `MyNote Page` or if they have visited any other page.
To move pages I use the `PushModalAsync()` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to the previous page using PopAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817388/how-to-pass-data-to-the-previous-page-using-popasync)

Comment: You can find all the currently open pages in `Navigation.NavigationStack`

Comment: Popasync by definition removes the top page from navigation stack