# How do you pass data from Navigation.PopAsync to previous page?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have seen other questions regarding passing data between navigation pages but I can't seem to pass an int from Page2 to Page1.

I have Page1 that pushes another Pushes Page2, when a button is clicked on Page2 I Pop the content page and need to pass an integer to Page1.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could use MessagingCenter, you could pass an object or VM instance when creating page2 and set the return value on that object, you could pass a delegate that Page2 can call when it completes, etc.  There are many different ways to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh the one but last ContentPage on the Navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465850/how-to-refresh-the-one-but-last-contentpage-on-the-navigation)

Comment: I've heard MC isn't the best way to handle this type of problem... I'm a beginner though, so i'll try.

Answer (score 2):

### I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0) on Events and Delegates and got it running!

Page1:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static int _player;
    public static int Player
    {
        get{ return _player; }
        set{ _player = value; }
    }

    public NewGameH(string homeTeam, string opponentTeam)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnPlayerSet(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Begin Player {0} ", Player);
    }

    async void button1_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var page2 = new Page2();
        page2.PlayerSet += this.OnPlayerSet;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page2);
    }
}
```

Page2:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage{
    public delegate void SetPlayerEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
    public event SetPlayerEventHandler PlayerSet;

    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected virtual void OnPlayerSet(){
        if (PlayerSet != null){
            PlayerSet(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    async void button2_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Page1.Player=1;
        OnPlayerSet();
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```